# Openpyxl causing Excel to repair and remove datavalidation when I try and add DV values to a cell using string formatting, but not if I specify values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like the below with 3 columns. Possible Matches will have one name if the Match Score is 100 and multiple names if it's not. I'm trying to output this file to excel using openpyxl.

| Index | Tracker_Name | Possible Matches | Match Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alberta Investment Management Corporation | alberta investment management corporation | 100 |
| 2 | Acharya Capital | karya capital, hara capital, ara capital, a capital, Create New Database Entry | 63.66124359 |

I am trying to figure out how to make the the possible matches output to Excel as data validation. My code is below, essentially, I'm attempting to check if the match score is less than 100, if it's not, it'll output the pandas dataframe row to Excel as is.

If it's less than 100, then I'd like the second column to add a data validation where the list of possible values is limited to the names in the Possible Matches cell of my pandas dataframe.

```
    workbook = load_workbook(filename='output_test.xlsx.xlsm')

# Select a worksheet
worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']


for r, row in enumerate(dataframe_to_rows(df_excel, index=False, header=False), start=1):
    if row[2] == 100:
        for c, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
            worksheet.cell(row=r, column=c, value=value)
    else:
        for c, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
            if c == 2:
                dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1="{}".format(value))
                worksheet.add_data_validation(dv)
                dv.add(worksheet.cell(row=r, column=c))
            else:
                worksheet.cell(row=r, column=c, value=value)

# Save the changes to the Excel workbook
workbook.save('output_text.xlsx')
```

No matter what I do, every time I run this code and go to open the workbook, Excel will give me the following error:

[image]

[image]

However, if I change the line of code to just be set values like the below, it works without any issues.

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"dog, cat, mouse"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enclose the `value` with single quotes (`' '`) so Excel can interpret it as a string and not as a formula when, since you deal with [*manipulating cells*](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html).

Replace this :

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1="{}".format(value))
```

by this :

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1="'{}'".format(value))
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same issue. It still repairs and removes data validation after making the change and running the code.

Comment: value = {str} 'ara capital, a capital, karya capital, hara capital, Create New Database Entry'